# Match parts of a URL starting with the end and looking back

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

Using regex (and the JavaScript flavor of it) how do I match the first bunch of URLs but not the second and then the other way around?

I've got all twisted up with maybe starting with the pi (they all have that) and then looking behind for a forward slash and some numbers but I'll admit I'm lost.

```
Group 1:

https://my.domain.com/?pi123=20&pi637=2
https://my.domain.com/?pi123=20&pi637=3
https://my.domain.com/?pi123=21
https://my.domain.com/?pi123=21&pi637=2
https://my.domain.com/?pi123=22
https://my.domain.com/p/mypage?pi7666=37
https://my.domain.com/p/mypagejonothing?pi1286=14
https://my.domain.com/hello/jo-nothing/?pi5676=1&pi8973=45
https://my.domain.com/hello/aword-anotherword-perhapsmore/f/words-words-stuff-stuff-stuff
https://my.domain.com/hello/aword-anotherword-perhapsmore/f/words-words-stuff-stuff-stuff#pi8765=2
https://my.domain.com/hello/aword-anotherword-perhapsmore/f/words-words-stuff-stuff-stuff?pi8765=2


Group 2:

https://my.domain.com/hello/aword-anotherword-perhapsmore/f/words-words-stuff-stuff-stuff/7654321/anyword-anyword-anyword-anyword-anyword-anyword-anyword
https://my.domain.com/hello/aword-anotherword-perhapsmore/f/words-words-stuff-stuff-stuff/7654321/anyword-anyword-anyword-anyword-anyword-anyword-anyword#pi2151=3
https://my.domain.com/hello/aword-anotherword-perhapsmore/f/words-words-stuff-stuff-stuff/7654321/anyword-anyword-anyword-anyword-anyword-anyword-anyword#pi2151=5
https://my.domain.com/hello/jo-nothing/f/word/123456/one-five-twelve-random-length45-3-1?pi2151=2
https://my.domain.com/hello/jo-nothing/f/yes-no-yes/54321/test-one-way#pi2151=2
https://my.domain.com/hello/jo-nothing/f/no-yes/123456/one-five-twelve-random-length45-3-1#pi2151=2
```

It has to be the JavaScript flavour of regex and two separate patterns (one match those URLs in the first, then a 2nd pattern for the other group).

Comment: So, what is the distinction between the groups ?

Comment: Hey @MDR, unless you can distinguish the difference between group 1 and 2 it is a useless question. I'm voting to close.

Comment: Ahoy @sin thanks for trying.  Maybe I didn't explain it very well.  I got close enough with matching group 1 using ^(?!.*\/\d{1,8}\/).*pi\d.*$ while NOT matching group 2 and that's working well enough for me: https://regex101.com/r/RXi0hQ/1  Thanks again!  I appreciate it.

Comment: Then, what's the difference between group 1 and group 2 ?